# Null check in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

A question I previously asked [System.NotSupportedException - Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41822019/2004251)

was replied with the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41822351/2004251

The method in the above question was modified from the below

```
public List<User> GetActiveUsers(int? officeID, string roleID, string query)
{
    return (from user in GetDBContext.User
            join userRole in GetDBContext.UserRole
                on user.UserID equals userRole.UserID
            join userOffice in GetDBContext.UserAuthorizedOffice
                on user.UserID equals userOffice.UserID
            where user.IsActive == true &&
                    user.UserTypeID == 1 &&
                    userOffice.IsAuthorized &&
                    userOffice.Office.IsActive &&
                    (userOffice.OfficeID == officeID || officeID == null) &&
                    string.Equals(userRole.RoleID, roleID) &&
                    (user.FirstName + user.LastName).Contains(query)
            select user).ToList();
}
```

This method works as expected.

My question : if `null` check works in this method, why does it not work when the input parameter is converted to `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: I'm not a SQL expert, but this is my guess. In this instance, it is seeing if a single `int?` value is equal to null, which has a SQL equivalent. In the referenced question, you are checking if an entire collection is null, which is not as straightforward to convert into a SQL statement.

Comment: Which _input parameter_ is changed to `IEnumerable<int>`, officeID? That would be  a completely different query.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, `int? officeID` has been changed to `IEnumerable<int> officeIDs`

Answer (score 0):

In the first case your type is an `IEnumerable` which doesn't have any equal in `SQL`. But the second case is a nullable `int` that `SQL` has an exact type for that:

> a column with `int` data type and checked allow nulls.

So `officeID == null` can be converted to an expression in `SQL` side by entity framework, but `IEnumerable` is not a type that can be recognized by `SQL` and on the other hand, it's value is a reference in memory. How do you want to check in `SQL` that a pointed location in your application memory doesn't point to a null object.

Answer (score 0):

With collections, use Contains() instead, this will return Users if their officeID is in your collection.

```
    public List<User> GetActiveUsers(IEnumerable<int> officeIDs, string roleID, string query)
    {
        return (from user in GetDBContext.User
                    join userRole in GetDBContext.UserRole
                    on user.UserID equals userRole.UserID
                    join userOffice in GetDBContext.UserAuthorizedOffice
                    on user.UserID equals userOffice.UserID
                    where user.IsActive == true &&
                          user.UserTypeID == 1 &&
                          userOffice.IsAuthorized &&
                          userOffice.Office.IsActive &&
                          officeIDs.Contains(userOffice.Office)
                          string.Equals(userRole.RoleID, roleID) &&
                          (user.FirstName + user.LastName).Contains(query)
                    select user).ToList();
    }
```

Then you can combine this with a null check and execute a different query depending on the result:

```
return officeIDs != null
                    ? (from user in GetDBContext.User
                        join userRole in GetDBContext.UserRole
                        on user.UserID equals userRole.UserID
                        join userOffice in GetDBContext.UserAuthorizedOffice
                        on user.UserID equals userOffice.UserID
                        where user.IsActive == true &&
                              user.UserTypeID == 1 &&
                              userOffice.IsAuthorized &&
                              userOffice.Office.IsActive &&
                              officeIDs.Contains(userOffice.Office)
                              string.Equals(userRole.RoleID, roleID) &&
                              (user.FirstName + user.LastName).Contains(query)
                        select user).ToList();
                    : (from user in GetDBContext.User
                        join userRole in GetDBContext.UserRole
                        on user.UserID equals userRole.UserID
                        join userOffice in GetDBContext.UserAuthorizedOffice
                        on user.UserID equals userOffice.UserID
                        where user.IsActive == true &&
                              user.UserTypeID == 1 &&
                              userOffice.IsAuthorized &&
                              userOffice.Office.IsActive &&
                              string.Equals(userRole.RoleID, roleID) &&
                              (user.FirstName + user.LastName).Contains(query)
                        select user).ToList();
```